# SIGSEGV fault on CodeChef

Tags: c

[the problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/COUNTP)

my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int T,A[100];
    scanf("%d",&T);
    
    while(T--)
    {
        int N,sum=0,rem;
        scanf("%d",&N);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i]);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)
        {
            sum+=A[i];
        }
        
        rem=sum%2;
        if(rem==1)
        printf("NO\n");
        if(rem==0)
        printf("YES\n");
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

- `T` is the number of test cases
- `A` is the array formed by the numbers in the input , the size of which I've initialized to 100
- `N` is the actual size of the array of the numbers in the input
- `sum` is the sum of the elements of the array , which I've initialized to 0

Sample Input:

```
4
4
1 1 2 2
6
1 2 4 6 8 10
2
3 5
3
1 3 5
```

Sample Output:

```
YES
NO
YES
NO
```

When I run this code on the IDE , I get the required output for the given sample input , but when I submit , it gives me a runtime error(SIGSEGV).
I've checked the entire code thoroughly and there doesn't seem to be any error in it to me.

Comment: What if `T` (or `N`) is greater than 100?

Comment: Your code supports arbitrarily large `T`, but `N` only up to 100 because that's the dimension of `A`.  Which is an altogether arbitrary restriction, since you don't need `A` (as an array) at all.  Just keep a running sum instead of reading all the numbers into an array and then summing them separately.

Comment: You don't check the return value from `scanf()`; if it fails, you are operating on undefined data.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know how to reproduce your segfault so let's fix the issues observed:

1. Ensure T >= 0 by using `unsigned` instead of `int`.
2. Don't store the values in A, just the current value.  If you need to store them either malloc the array or use a VLA `int A[N]`.
3. Check return value from `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned T;
    if(scanf("%u",&T) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed (T)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(T--) {
        unsigned N;
        if(scanf("%u",&N) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed (N)\n");
            return 1;
        }
        int sum=0;
        for(unsigned i = 0 ; i<N ; i++) {
            int A;
            if(scanf("%d",&A) != 1) {
                printf("scanf failed (A)\n");
                return 1;
            }
            sum+=A;
        }
        printf("%s\n", sum % 2 ? "NO" : "YES");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constraints of the problem

```
1 <= T <= 10^5
2 <= N <= 10^5
1 <= Ai <= 10^9
The sum of N across all test cases won't exceed 10^6
```

The size of the array 'A' caused the problem.

The size of 'N' can be maximum 10^5.
In a test case, if size N is more than 100, then your code'll give RTE.
You need to declare a bigger size of the array (~10^6 + 1).